# oracle get current date along with data from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm unable to find such example in the web. I'm not an oracle user (I've been using mysql). As I read in the web, you shall use "FROM DUAL" in Oracle, when the data is not fetched from a real table (a function, for example). But how what can I do when I want to attach current date, e.g. `SYSDATE` when retrieving some real table data?

Let's say I've got an A table with col1 and col2 columns. Is any of the following correct? If not, please write a correct one:

```
SELECT col1, col2, SYSDATE
FROM A;

SELECT col1, col2, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM A;

SELECT col1, col2, TRUNC(SYSDATE)
FROM A;

SELECT col1, col2, TRUNC(SYSDATE)
FROM A, DUAL;
```

Unfortunately, I don't have an oracle installation to test this... that's why I write it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

They all look correct to me.  The fourth uses comma in the `from` clause.  I encourage you to never use commas in the `from` clause.  Instead, always use explicit `join` syntax, replacing the comma with a `cross join`.  However, the use of `dual` is pretty useless in that particular query.

You should learn about SQL Fiddle ([www.sqlfiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)).  This is a place where you can try out your code on several different databases.

Comment: +1 thanks for sqlfiddle! PS I know it's not good to make implicit joins, but my question was do I have to use `DUAL` when fetching data from a real table.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz . . . No, you do not.  You only need dual when you want to put constants into a query in some form.  (Perhaps there is another situation.  I should be careful with "only".)